# how to use firebase cloud function pubsub.schedule?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Today, there is new feature of Cloud Functions for Firebase which is running functions on a schedule. So I tried to test the sample code.

### index.js file

```
exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule(‘every 5 minutes’).onRun((context) => {
  console.log(‘This will be run every 5 minutes!’);
});
```

---

But when I tried to deploy this, I got the following error message:

---

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: functions.pubsub.schedule is not a function
```

---

My firebase tools version is `6.7` (updated today)

What is the solution?

I checked the example git code in here (https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron/functions/index.js)

But it also cause the same error:

> functions.pubsub.schedule is not a function

Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes').onRun((context) => {
   console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
});
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [announcement blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html) points out that the version of the firebase-functions module also needs to be minimum 2.3.0.  Run `npm install firebase-functions@latest` in your functions folder to update it, then build and deploy again.

Comment: This one fixed the issue for me. If it fixed your issue too @SssSteve, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked for me. Installed in the functions root folder.

Comment: I got this error functions[scheduledFunction]: function ignored because the pubsub.googleapis.com emulator does not exist or is not running.

Comment: I am using  "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0" , still i am having this issue

Answer (score 3):

Here's the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions

```
export const scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 5 minutes')
.timeZone('Asia/Jakarta')
.onRun((context) => {
    console.log('This will be run every 5 minutes!');
});
```

And you can set the timeZone as additional

Comment: Not relating at all

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue.

I had to update my `firebase-tools` to version `^6.7.2`. 
I have also updated `firebase-functions` but that alone did not do the job. So I would update all firebase dependencies (firebase-tools/admin/functions).